# 2 inline-block divs wont line up when total width is 100%

Tags: css

I have 2 divs one at 15% width and the other at 85% width (total 100%) set as inline-blocks with a float:left and a float:right to keep them on their sides.

But when put into practice the 85% div appears underneath the 15% div with some overlap. The link below shows exactly how i have it setup. i need them to be perfectly next to each other taking 100% of the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/6favu1gr/1/

my css:

```
#main_cont {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}

#sidenav {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding: 15px;
    width:15%;
    background-color: #130103;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(38,2,6,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(38,2,6,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(38,2,6,1);
    border: 1px solid #938082;
}

#main {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width:79%;
    background-color: #130103;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(38,2,6,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(38,2,6,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(38,2,6,1);
    border: 1px solid #938082;
}
```

I've tried smaller %'s but when decreasing the windows size they overlap again.

Comment: It's not about `inline-block`s. By floating inline-level elements, the computed value of `display` would be `block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have padding which you're not accounting for. One way to account for it is to set the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to border-box:

```
#main, #sidenav {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6favu1gr/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

In box model the width is inside if you add padding so your element is larger then 15%. You can fix that using:

```
#sidenav, #main {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6favu1gr/3/)